# 動画ファイルを新規に読み込み、すべてデータを読み込み終わってから再生を始めたい

Tags: html5

ネットワークドライブに置いたexaple.mp4を新規に読み込み、
すべてデータを読み込み終わってから再生を始めたいです。
example.mp4は100MBくらいあり、index.htmとexample.mp4は
ネットワークドライブに置いてあります。

キャッシュを使わないように下記のように書いてみました。

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
<body>
<video src="example.mp4" width="1280" height="720" controls  preload="auto" autoplay></video>
```

しかし、あまりに早く表示されるので、キャッシュを再生している
or
動画の読み込み途中で再生を始めているのではと疑っています。
修正すべき点があればご教示ください。

ブラウザはFirefox39.0.3で検証しています。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

まず、`autoplay` は、停止しない程度にバッファリングして、再生可能になったら即座に再生を開始する、というフラグです。

> 1 番目の例では、データのダウンロードのために再生途中に一時停止する必要がない程度までデータを受信できると、自動的に再生が始まります。
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

よって、

> 動画の読み込み途中で再生を始めている

の理解は正しいと思います。

ではどうするかというと、本家で js で制御している回答を見つけました。

[html5 - Another: Force Chrome to fully buffer mp4 video - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251632/another-force-chrome-to-fully-buffer-mp4-video)

[javascript - Fully buffer video in Chrome - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628953/fully-buffer-video-in-chrome)

a. ajax で取得して、video タグの src に入れる方法と、
b. js に再生ボタンを押させて、全てバッファリングしてからDOMに追加する方法があるようです。

といっても、chrome と firefox は、バッファリングの仕方が異なるようで、そのままは使えないかもしれませんので、適宜修正されると宜しいかと思います。